# android application installed but doesn't open

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have just started my graduation project 
i made the main activity interface but when i install it on emulator or my mobile it just seems is if it's not installed and it doesn't run or open

i get this in the console

```
[2013-06-27 14:46:26 - ahliaevents] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'nexus'
[2013-06-27 14:46:26 - ahliaevents] Uploading ahliaevents.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-27 14:46:30 - ahliaevents] Installing ahliaevents.apk...
[2013-06-27 14:46:42 - ahliaevents] Success!
[2013-06-27 14:46:42 - ahliaevents] \ahliaevents\bin\ahliaevents.apk installed on device
[2013-06-27 14:46:42 - ahliaevents] Done!
```

Answer (score 1):

Put:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Into the `<activity>` tag in the manifest for the Activity you want to open upon installation and clicking in the launcher.